# Pantalla se oscurece cuando se abre modal

Tags: html, ajax, bootstrap

Cuando consulto la primera vez en mi form abre el modal y muestra la información pero cuando cierro, vuelvo a consultar la pantalla se oscurece y no abre el modal, entonces toca recargar la página para hacer otra consulta. El formulario es mediante ajax.

```
<script>
    function clickBtnEditInfodoc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?suppressHeaders=true&m=sgi&a=consultar",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                consultar: $("input[name='consultar']").val()
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Hubo un problema...");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#aj_info_document_modal_content").html(data);
                $("#aj_info_document_modal").modal("show"); 
            }
        });
    }
 </script>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <form name="Frm_consulta" action="" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); clickBtnEditInfodoc();">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="consultar"><b>Consultar:</b></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="consultar" value="<?php echo $buscar; ?>" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <strong>Escriba el código (Ej. BOMA000_1_1).</strong>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por lo general, eso se debe a que hay etiquetas sin cerrar... Además, no estás mostrando el modal. ¿Tenés la certeza de que el código está escrito correctamente? Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar un [repro].

Answer (score 1):

Prueba editando tu función de esta manera:

```
function clickBtnEditInfodoc() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?suppressHeaders=true&m=sgi&a=consultar",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            consultar: $("input[name='consultar']").val()
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Hubo un problema...");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#aj_info_document_modal_content").html(data);
            $("#aj_info_document_modal").modal("show");
        }
    });
}
```

En lugar de simplemente mostrar el modal después de la llamada AJAX (`$("#aj_info_document_modal").modal("show");`), también se actualiza el contenido del modal con `$("#aj_info_document_modal_content").html(data);`.